# Perl XML parsing to get data

Tags: xml, perl

Is it possible to use a perl script to get only the data (war, Europe, First etc) from an XML file like this and store them in a .txt file?

```
<Node id="93" /> 
  war 
  <Node id="102" /> 
  Europe 
  <Node id="112" /> 
  first 
  <Node id="117" /> 
  <Node id="118" /> 
  world
  <Node id="120" /> 
  <Node id="121" /> 
  country 
  <Node id="126" /> 
  fire
  <Node id="132" /> 
  <Node id="135" /> 
  The 
  <Node id="139" /> 
  Government
  <Node id="144" /> 
  has greeted 
  <Node id="157" /> 
  King
  <Node id="159" /> 
  <Node id="160" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML).

```
use XML::LibXML qw();
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'XML');
<root>
  <Node id="93" />
  war
  <Node id="102" />
  Europe
  <Node id="112" />
  first
  <Node id="117" />
  <Node id="118" />
  world
  <Node id="120" />
  <Node id="121" />
  country
  <Node id="126" />
  fire
  <Node id="132" />
  <Node id="135" />
  The
  <Node id="139" />
  Government
  <Node id="144" />
  has greeted
  <Node id="157" />
  King
  <Node id="159" />
  <Node id="160" />
</root>
XML

print $dom->textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm). It looks like all you want is the content part.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
my $xml = qq~<root>
<Node id="93" /> 
  war 
  <Node id="102" /> 
  Europe 
  <Node id="112" /> 
  first 
  <Node id="117" /> 
  <Node id="118" /> 
  world
  <Node id="120" /> 
  <Node id="121" /> 
  country 
  <Node id="126" /> 
  fire
  <Node id="132" /> 
  <Node id="135" /> 
  The 
  <Node id="139" /> 
  Government
  <Node id="144" /> 
  has greeted 
  <Node id="157" /> 
  King
  <Node id="159" /> 
  <Node id="160" />
</root>
~;

my $ref = XMLin($xml);
open $out, '>', 'output.txt' or die "Could not open output file";
print $out join "\n", map {s/\s{2,}//g;$_} @{$ref->{'content'}};
close $out;
```

There are other XML modules around that you could use as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open 1.xml ;
echo (/) ;
```